# Margin-Cite from tufte-book

Tags: citing, marginpar, tufte

I like the way the tufte-book documentclass is writing the full citation in the margin. Unfortunatly I use a pretty different documentclass, so that I don't have this feature.

I already looks into the tufte-common.def, but my TeX abilities are not as good that I can extract this into my document.

So here is my question. Is there a chance to re-define the cite{} environment, so that the citation is automaticallay written in the margin.

Beside of this, I want to write the Bibliography at the end of each chapter, so I use bibunits package (incompatibble to biblatex ;()

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Which documentclass and bibliography-packages are you using? Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your setup?

Comment: in General I use "The Legrand Orange Book" you can find it here:http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book with some changes. the biggest change is that I would like to use the bibliography at the end of each chapter, with the bibunit package. The rest is minor.